# jsf trying to update my form

Tags: jsf

I am trying to make an online examination system that reads and store data on mysql database.

Now I am trying to create the questions page and I am willing to make only one question on the page and the user can go to the next question by clicking next or back to the previous question by clicking previous, so my question is how to make the h:commandButton to update the question and the answer choices when the user click next baring in mind that the questions number may vary.

What I have so far is a managed bean that has a list and im able to retrive this list in the webpage but all questions are on the same page.

```
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat value="#{mbQuestion.questions}" var="value">

            <h3 align="left" style="color: white;">
                Question #{value.id} <br />
            </h3>


            <h3 align="left" style="color: white;">
                #{value.questionTxt} <br />
            </h3>
            <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive"
                style="width: 10%; color: white;">
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1_1" value="1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-11">
                        <label for="cb1_1" class="ui-widget"> 1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1_2" value="2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-11">
                        <label for="cb1_2" class="ui-widget">Option 2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1_3" value="3" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-11">
                        <label for="cb1_3" class="ui-widget">Option 3</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
```

can someone advice on how to do that?

Comment: What about using PrimeFaces? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml

Comment: @peterremec I dont know the number of questions that will be provided is there is a way to make this wizard dynamic?

Comment: @peterremec I will use c:foreach thanks for the advice its the most suffecient way for me.